# Tensorflow Image Recognition tutorial seemingly out of date?

Tags: python, classification, tensorflow

I am currently working through the [Image Recognition Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html) from the Tensorflow website but am having a hard time getting started...

I have installed Tensorflow through pip as per the instructions on the [repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#binary-installation).

When I cd in to my tensorflow installation (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow`) my `tensorflow/models/images` folder does not contain `imagenet/classify_image.py`. I cannot seem to find this python file anywhere on the web and would like to get started playing around with image classification.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm trying to access classify_image and it isn't working. I've tried downloading the script from the GitHub and running it but I get an error 
"A protocol message was rejected because it was too big"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'classify_image.py' isn't in the 0.5.0 released version which you have installed. But you can find the file you want [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py). Actually I think this is because the tutorial is up-to-date and the file is just uploaded to github two days ago. Maybe install from github is a better option for you because it is always up to date.

Answer (score 3):

As hsc points out, the `classify_image.py` script isn't in the binary release that you have installed (0.5.0). However, the script is compatible with the binary release, so you can download the script from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py), and run `python classify_image.py` to try it out. Alternatively, you can install the [latest binary version of TensorFlow (0.6.0)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#pip_install), which includes the `classify_image.py` script.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest binary version (0.6.0) but still no `imagenet/classify_image.py` in my images folder. I'll just download the script manually and run it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find this models folder in the tensorflow which is also in another tensorflow folder.

```
cd tensorflow/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet
```

In the imagenet folder, there is classify_image.py